# How to center the tick in the el-checkbox Element library element

Tags: vue.js, checkbox, size, element

Can anyone advice how can I style el-checkbox Elements library (https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/checkbox) element to change the checkbox height and width and to have the tick in the center of the checkbox.

I have changed the size of the text and the checkbox but now the tick is not centered.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The check mark selector is `.el-checkbox__inner::after`, and it's positioned `absolute`, so you'll have to set `height` and `left` accordingly.

The following CSS can style the various parts of the checkbox:

```css
.el-checkbox,
.el-checkbox__label {
  font-size: 22px;
}

/* checkbox */
.el-checkbox__inner {
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
}

/* check mark */
.el-checkbox__inner::after {
  height: 14px;
  left: 8px;
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/XWppoOo)